# Move modules via drag and drop on DotNetNuke layout editor?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I would like to move modules via drag and drop as an admin. It would have to trigger those same "Move to X Pane" links? [I saw this link that shows dragging and dropping modules as an admin for layout](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/GuidedTour/ModulesMove.htm), but could not get it to work.

Am I missing something or is there an extension for this? I am trying this on the latest DNN 6.0 by the way. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that guided tour is super old.  I believe it was DNN 5 where that behavior was changed to only work in layout mode.  Once you switch into layout mode, you should be able to see the panes and drag the modules between them (by their titles).

Comment: I see, it works in layout mode as you mentioned, but it really sucks. I am trying this in the latest DNN 6.0.

Comment: Yes, it does really suck.  I think that's part of the reason it's so hidden :-)

Comment: I am shocked the community has not jumped in with a plug in. I am trying to recreate how Sitefinity does it. Drag and drop widgets from a toolbox of widgets. Anyone know of one or want to go in on it with me?